# How does one create insertion or deletion mutations using LibFuzzer?

Tags: clang, fuzzing, libfuzzer

*libFuzzer* has functions that can be implemented by the end-user like this:

```c
size_t LLVMFuzzerCustomMutator(
     uint8_t* data, size_t size, size_t max_size, unsigned int seed)
```

Am I free to sometimes insert some bytes in `data` thereby making it larger; I assume `max_size` may not be exceeded? If I needed more bytes than `max_bytes` to perform the necessary insertion how would I do that? Do I return the new size?